# What is the cardinality of a string set with finite alphabet?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

We can construct a language $\mathcal L$ with the finite alphabet $\mathcal A $ (e.g. $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$):

$$
\mathcal L=\{string|string=x^* \land x\in \mathcal A\}
$$

$x^*$ is $x$'s **Kleene Closure**, which means repeat $x$ for zero or more times.

I got two conflicting results with two different ways.

#### Method 1

Let:
$$
\mathcal A=\{0,1,\dots,9\}\cup\{.\}\\
\mathbb{R}^{(0,1)}=\{x|0<x<1,x\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$

then: $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{(0,1)}$, $x$ can be writen in format of $0.231\dots$, so $ string\_of(x) \in \mathcal L$.

So: $card(\mathcal L) \ge card(\mathbb{R}^{(0,1)}) = \aleph_1$

#### Method 2

We can arrange elements of $\mathcal L$ in aspect of string length:

Let $\mathcal A=\{0,1,\dots,9\}$, $num\_of(string)$ is the decimal value of the $string$

$$
\mathcal{L} = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \mathcal{L}_i \\
\mathcal{L}_0 = \{string|string \in \mathcal L \land len(string)=0\} \\
\mathcal{L}_1 = \{string|string \in \mathcal L \land len(string)=1\} \\
\mathcal{L}_2 = \{string|string \in \mathcal L \land len(string)=2\} \\
\dots
$$

And for each $\mathcal{L}_i$ can be arranged as:

$$
\mathcal{L}_i=\{string_i^0, string_i^1,\dots,\dots,string_i^n\} \\
$$
where $n={\|\mathcal{A}\|^i}, 
\forall j,k,  0 \lt j \lt k \lt n, num\_of(string_i^j) \lt num\_of(string_i^k) $.

so I can arrange all of $\mathcal{L}$'s element in order, which means $card(\mathcal{L}) \le \aleph_0$

I cannot figure out the mistake of these two methods, can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with this type of thing so forgive me if I'm being naive, but could it be that in the first method, you are counting strings that are actually *infinite* in length while in the second method you are really only taking the union of all finite length strings?

Comment: @KSab seems like right, while a proof is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that the decimal expansion of a real number is not a finite string, so it is not in the Kleene closure of the alphabet.

If you agree that "Eventually $0$" can be exchanged with "finite" in this case, then you still didn't even manage to get $\frac13$ into your Kleene closure, let alone any irrational number.

Comment: You mean the infinite string cannot be constructed by Kleene closure?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: So any length of string can be constructed by Kleene closure, but once it is constructed, it is finite? And the conclusion is: $card(\mathcal L)=\aleph_0$ ?

Comment: Yes. Any finite string is constructed. But no infinite string is constructed.

Comment: The rational number in $(0,1)$ cannot be represented by strings from $\mathcal L$. And method 2 is a valid arrangement, in this case each string is given a distinct natural number.